# Angular JS - Removing DOM elements that have another directive / scope attached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that will remove DOM elements from a page under certain conditions. It'll first remove the child elements, and then remove the parent. It works fine, but if there is another directive on the element, I can see some errors show up. I'm thinking it has to do with the scope of the other directive still existing after the element is removed.

What is the proper way to handle something like this? Do I need to destroy the scope of the other directive? The directive that removes the element has an inherited scope, and the other directive on the same element usually has an isolated scope.

Comment: Standard way is to handle those scenarios is to use `$scope.on('$destroy', function() {<clean up your external watchers!>}`. You should handle those event in the directives causing the error, not the directive that is removing an element (and obviously, the best place to do this is link function).